# SQL SSRS, Expression iif sum not calculating as expected

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-tablix

I am currently writing a SSRS report, my main data is populated into a table already by  SQL coded, I have added another table below to summarise the data.

the issues i am having is when i enter an expression with more than 1 if  the results given are not as expected
the expression i have is below:

`=iif(reportitems!country1.Value = Fields!country.Value and Fields!Loc_Quality.Value = "GOOD",sum(Fields!Qty_Ordered.Value),nothing)`

giving the resultant below

[![results given ][1]][1]

i should be expecting

[![expected results][2]][2]

is there something i am missing here or am i just trying to do something that isn't possible logically ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ2vF.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAwtQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
=SUM(
     IIF(
         reportitems!country1.Value = Fields!country.Value and  Fields!Loc_Quality.Value = "GOOD",
         Fields!Qty_Ordered.Value,
         Nothing
        )
     )
```

Comment: Hi Alan, I have tried this approach, But  as I am using a Report Item which is not in a header  I cannot use the aggregate function this way. Ironically I have removed the  the reference to the Country fields and I am now getting the correct out put!

`=SUM(
     IIF(
         Fields!Loc_Quality.Value = "GOOD",
         Fields!Qty_Ordered.Value,
         Nothing
        )
     )`

Comment: As didn't know your report structure so I could only go off what you had supplied. The point of my answer was to move the IIF inside the sum rather than the way you were doing it.

Comment: No Problem, Thank you for your help though :D